# How to add maps in java GUI (like GMap.net for c#)?

Tags: java, maps

C# has a a nice library/api to use for creating/using maps with winforms found at [Gmap.net](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) Does java have any libraries like this?

The closest thing I've found was [worldwind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) but this doesn't look half as good as what GMap.net does in winforms

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name make this an answer so I can award you in answering the question. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These libraries might help

- Generic Swing component: https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2
- Integration with JavaFX: http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/