# Free map for creating map image showing my GPS points

Tags: java, dictionary, gps

i need to create java application that generates image showing user defined points on a map. Is there any free java library containing free maps that I can use for this purpose?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15709870/330315 (together with OpenStreetMap)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Google Maps. Hope it help

Comment: Google maps is interesting solution. But there are request limits to google maps (think about 2500 requests per day).